# Django, ho to set queryset to zero value if empty

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have the following code in my views.py, that give me the `iva_debito_totale`That I figure out in my templates as table. But if the Ricavi models are empty, also my `iva_debito_totale` is empty. I have the necessity to have anyhow `iva_debito_totale`almost equal to zero, even if  Ricavi is empty.

This is my code

```
defaults = list(0 for m in range(13))
iva_debito = dict()
for year, month, totale in(Ricavi.objects.values_list( 'data_contabile__year', 'data_contabile__month').
        annotate(totale=ExpressionWrapper(Sum(F('quantita') * F('ricavo')*(F('iva')+0)),
        output_field=FloatField())).values_list('data_contabile__year', 'data_contabile__month', 'totale')) :
        iva_debito[id]=list(defaults)
        index=month
        iva_debito[id][index]=totale

iva_debito_totale={'IVA a Debito Totale': [sum(t) for t in zip(*iva_debito.values())],}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar situation once. This worked for me:

```
try:
   #query to get objects
except yourmodel.DoesNotExist:
   #set_variable=0
```

Comment: could you explain me better?